# OpenVPN: restrict a client to certain IP addresses

Tags: firewall, openvpn

I have an OpenVPN system with a number of users. I need to restrict some of the users so they can only connect from certain source IP addresses. It's not possible to simply firewall the OpenVPN port as I have other users that need to be able to connect from anywhere.

Is there a way to configure OpenVPN to restrict some clients to certain IP addresses?

By the way, this question is NOT a duplicate of this:
[Force (limit) OpenVPN client's IP/IPv6/lladdress](https://serverfault.com/questions/200610/force-limit-openvpn-clients-ip-ipv6-lladdress)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do this by writing a `client-connect` script that checks the source IP of the connection (in the `trusted_ip` or `trusted_ip6` env var) and then returns non-zero if it doesn't like it.  You'll need to set `script-security` to `2` in order to permit OpenVPN to actually run your script.